# Why Linux command called tee

Tags: meaning, terminology, technical

I've tried to find etymology of Linux command `tee` that splits standard output onto two another outputs. Have anyone reference on this history or word origin?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't appear to be about the English language.

Comment: It's a metaphor based the shape of the capital letter `T`. The top line represents the pipe from input to output, while the descender is the pipe leading down to save a copy to a file.

Comment: @JHCL Isn't questions about etymology English language related topic?

Comment: @Dewfy - if it's an English language word, you could look up the meaning and etymology yourself. Come back here if you're still not sure. If it's not an English word, it's off topic

Comment: @Dewfy: I don't need accepting, thanks. BTW, it's not just Linux but all versions of [UNIX™](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/routledge/unixlanguage.pdf).

Comment: @JohnLawler I've been using Linux for over a decade and never knew this. Awesome stuff, thanks.

Comment: It's not even directly based on the letter T; it's based on a physical [pipe tee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piping_and_plumbing_fitting#Tee) since the process of redirecting input and output is called "using pipes" or "piping".  (The physical pipe tee bears an obvious resemblance to the letter.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Linux/Unix uses several plumbing references (like 'piping' output to another command with the | character).
A 'tee' in plumbing is a part that is so-called for it's shape, which looks like the letter 'T'.  And it routes it's contents in two different directions.